# Extracting a certain value from the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What do you think will be the most optimal way to extract the value from the window.location.href.

This is the example  `http://localhost:3000/brand/1/brandCategory/3`
the Route will always be the same, just the numbers will change depending on what is chosen.

the brand id will be the first number and the category id is the second I need help extracting them in a react/typescript project.

keep in mind that it should work when the page is deployed and that the start of the URL will have a different name than localhost, but the routes will be the same.

I tried doing it with string formatting, but it's really unpredictable, tried also with regex but when I try to extract it typescript cries about the object is possibly 'null', what can you suggest?

```
Number(window.location.href.match(new RegExp(/\/[0-9]\//,'gm'))[0].split('/')[1])
```

this is the regex try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the path, remove empty segments and retrieve the numbers by position:

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/brand/1/brandCategory/3';
const segments = url.split('/').filter(seg => seg);
const length = segments.length;

console.log(`brand: ${segments[length - 3]}, brandCategory: ${segments[length - 1]}`);
```

I added the filter for the case of a trailing slash.

You could replace the filter with `endsWith`

```js
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/brand/1/brandCategory/3';
const segments = url.split('/');
const length = url.endsWith('/') ? segments.length - 1 : segments.length;

console.log(`brand: ${segments[length - 3]}, brandCategory: ${segments[length - 1]}`);
```

Comment: my bad, its working fine I had some conditions that changed the url, thank you!